# Record events if values have changed in the last 3 days

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a question, I have a table of importance. But the difference between these values is 3 days.

```html
select 
    er.name,
    er.temp as real_temp, 
    der.temp as old_temp
from TEMPR_SILO er
    left join TEMPR_SILO der
    on er.name = der.name
where der.ID_TRANS in (select max(ID_TRANS) - 72 from TEMPR_SILO) 
    and er.ID_TRANS  in (select max(ID_TRANS) from TEMPR_SILO)
```

My answer

```html
NAME       REAL_TEMP OLD_TEMP
SENSOR0001 7.98     9.66
SENSOR0002 8.04     9.91
SENSOR0003 7.91     0.41
SENSOR0004 9.54    -0.27
SENSOR0005 9.85    -1.09
SENSOR0006 9.35    -1.59
SENSOR0007 8.54    -1.34
```

That is, in the answer I have the name of the sensor, and the temperature is real and old which is already 3 days. I have a question, can I make it so that if the temperature drops to 5, then I have a spare ALARM table that

```html
 INSERT INTO ALARM ( NAME, INFO)    VALUES ( er.name ,'The temperature has greatly changed')
```

The table will have 600 values always. Thanks for the help)
I want to implement this code in a background task that will be called every hour)

Comment: The der condition in the WHERE clause makes the LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. If you want true LEFT JOIN result, move that condition to the ON clause.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, I understand that, but ID_TRANS is increasing every hour by 1. So I use where. And the answer is true!

Comment: Then switch to INNER JOIN, to make code clearer for everyone else, including me.

Answer (score 0):

You may add following query in your background task that will serve the purpose.

```
INSERT INTO IMS.ALARM (NAME,INFO)  
select er.name,'The temperature has significantly dropped'
from IMS.TEMPR_SILO er
    left join IMS.TEMPR_SILO der on er.name = der.name
where der.ID_TRANS in (select max(ID_TRANS) - 72 from IMS.TEMPR_SILO) 
and er.ID_TRANS  in (select max(ID_TRANS) from IMS.TEMPR_SILO)
and der.temp-er.temp>=6;
```

In my opinion, your solution can be little improved if you manage Alarming stuff in Trigger instead of some background process because there are some drawbacks in this way e.g.

- Continuous background process will be doing hourly extra DB I/O in addition
  to consuming processing power
- For any given reasons, if new records are not coming then program may register/insert new alarms on the basis of obsolete data

However, if you write a trigger 'ON INSERT' event on same table TEMPR_SILO by using above mentioned query then:

- It will be executed automatically as and when new record gets inserted
- False Alarms can be avoided
- No background process will be required

I hope this solution will work for you.