# Selection by date in request oracle (between)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I wrote a query that I use in the apex oracle, in which I added filters, but when I add a date selection this query does not work (although there are no syntax errors). I'll be grateful for the help

```
select eb.ID,
       eb.NAME,
       eb.TEMP,
       eb.ID_TRANS,
       eb.CR_DATE,
       eb.DATE_TMRT,
       ah.name as Silo_name,
       we.name as ORGANIZATIONS,
       ad.name as item
              from TEMPR_SILO  eb
              left join  ORGANIZATIONS we on  eb.ORGANIZATIONS =  we.id
              left join  ITEM_CRITICALTEMP ad on  ad.id <> 0 
              left join  silo ah  on  ah.id = ad.id_silo 
where   (:P115_ORG is null or we.name = :P115_ORG) 
and (:P115_SILO_NAME is null or  ah.name = :P115_SILO_NAME) 
and  to_timestamp(eb.DATE_TMRT)  between to_timestamp(:P115_DATA1,'dd.mm.yyyy') and to_timestamp(:P115_DATA2,'dd.mm.yyyy') 
------ when "OR" is missing then everything works ---
or   (:P115_DATA2 is null OR :P115_DATA1 is null)
group by
       eb.ID,
       eb.NAME,
       eb.TEMP,
       eb.ID_TRANS,
       eb.CR_DATE,
       eb.DATE_TMRT,
       we.name,
       ah.name,
       ad.name
```

But filtered dates may not be specified, and I need all records to be available, and therefore "OP" should be. I would be grateful if you could help me find the error!

Comment: Apex_MAN, is this still an issue? Have you reviewed the answers below?

Comment: @DanMcGhan Yes, this is a problem, in the answers below it hides only the quola to give not empty.If empty then a mistake! , but there is also another problem with mpen. I have done it this way that when I change at least one of the ITEMs, then I have a dynamic action (updating the page with new ITEM parameters), but I want to create a button under them to clear all filters. Where I also use a dynamic action in which I assign all ITEMs to null. But then there is a continuous reload of the page. And I cannot solve this problem (

Comment: @DanMcGhan It turns out that I have 3 filters (: P115_SILO_NAME,: P115_ORG, and: P115_DATA1,: P115_DATA2), but correctly everything except dates (

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding you, but let's try to stay focused on the fact that you're having difficulty with date filters. What do you mean by they don't work correctly? Do you get an error, do no rows come back, or something else? What is the datatype of `eb.DATE_TMRT`? Give me an example of a value you tested in P115_DATA1 and P115_DATA2.

Comment: @DanMcGhan (:P115_ORG is null or we.name = :P115_ORG) 
and (:P115_SILO_NAME is null or  ah.name = :P115_SILO_NAME) 
and  (to_timestamp(eb.DATE_TMRT,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  between to_timestamp(:BV1,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and to_timestamp(:BV2,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
or   (:BV2 is null OR :BV1 is null))

Comment: @DanMcGhan When I use this code, it does not show records per itid. and only for the date: BV2. Example: "and (to_timestamp (eb.DATE_TMRT, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24: mi: ss') between to_timestamp ('09. 03.2020 10:22:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24: mi: ss' ) and to_timestamp ('10 .03.2020 10:22:00 ',' dd.mm.yyyy hh24: mi: ss') "will only be shown below on 10/03/2020 and no on 09/03/2020

Comment: Apex_Man, please don't type comments like you're doing. Please update the question instead. For example, BV2 isn't even in the original question. Instead of these comments, please make a nice, clear question with lots of details and properly formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

I presume it should have been

```
where
  (                                                              --> this 
       (:P115_ORG is null or we.name = :P115_ORG) 
   and (:P115_SILO_NAME is null or  ah.name = :P115_SILO_NAME) 
   and  to_timestamp(eb.DATE_TMRT)  between to_timestamp(:P115_DATA1,'dd.mm.yyyy') 
                                        and to_timestamp(:P115_DATA2,'dd.mm.yyyy') 
  )                                                              --> this
  --
  or   (:P115_DATA2 is null OR :P115_DATA1 is null)
```

i.e. enclose all `AND` conditions into their own brackets, and leave `OR` condition out of it.

Comment: thanks for the help, could you still look at one of my questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60503335/record-events-if-values-have-changed-in-the-last-3-days

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that one of the condition`(BETWEEN/NULL)` should be true.
Change the following

```
and  to_timestamp(eb.DATE_TMRT)  between to_timestamp(:P115_DATA1,'dd.mm.yyyy') and to_timestamp(:P115_DATA2,'dd.mm.yyyy') 
------ when "OR" is missing then everything works ---
or   (:P115_DATA2 is null OR :P115_DATA1 is null)
```

to

```
and  (to_timestamp(eb.DATE_TMRT)  between to_timestamp(:P115_DATA1,'dd.mm.yyyy') and to_timestamp(:P115_DATA2,'dd.mm.yyyy') 
------ when "OR" is missing then everything works ---
or   (:P115_DATA2 is null OR :P115_DATA1 is null))
```

I think it should work.

Second scenario: when all the conditions or `Null` condition should be true:

```
(
(:P115_ORG is null or we.name = :P115_ORG) 
and (:P115_SILO_NAME is null or  ah.name = :P115_SILO_NAME) 
and  to_timestamp(eb.DATE_TMRT)  between to_timestamp(:P115_DATA1,'dd.mm.yyyy') and to_timestamp(:P115_DATA2,'dd.mm.yyyy')
) 
or   (:P115_DATA2 is null OR :P115_DATA1 is null)
```